# I want to create an open source cloud storing and sharing system, where should i start?

Tags: encryption, cloud, openstack, eucalyptus, cloud-storage

I actually want to create a public cloud which communicates with another server deployed somewhere and the communication has to be encrypted and my friends should be able to access the public cloud to download files stored in the cloud.

As this is a college project, i think i could use private cloud setup in my laptop  instead of public cloud and another laptop as a client and one more laptop as a server which should communicate with the private cloud of my laptop and how should i progress with this project implementation.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you to start with SWIFT object storage. Its an open stack based object store.

You can get details about swift object store here : http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/

More over if you are developing it on java you can use either jcloud or joss as a client. Using the joss you can upload a file an get a public URL from where the object can be downloadable.

To know about jcloud : https://jclouds.apache.org/

To know about joss : http://joss.javaswift.org/

Comment: sir.I read about creating a private cloud in eucalyptus and i am very confused which one to use and can you throw me some light about the whole concept.

Comment: You can use any cloud, from your question what I can get is that you need to store some files in cloud and from there others will be downloading it. It is totally my point of view that using swift object storage may make your life simpler (may be because I am familiar with it) as it is a open stack based cloud solution where you can create a object out of your files and upload it to a container. then you can generate a url (public/private : depending on your need), which can be use to download your object. But there is no harm on exploring other cloud capabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much..Can you specify me the system requirements for the whole project?

Comment: Everything is in the net search and find out. we are here to help you only if you are struck by all other means. Do an exploration and research